# Dynamic R dataframes - change yes/no responses to 1/0

Tags: r, dataframe, dynamic, dplyr

I use an API call to LimeSurvey to get data into a Shiny R app I'm working on.  I then manipulate the dataframe so that I have only the responses given by a certain individual over time.  The dataframe can look like this:

```
Appetite <- c("No","Yes","No","No","No","No","No","No","No")
Dental.Health <- c("No","Yes","No","No","No","No","Yes","Yes","No")
Dry.mouth <- c("No","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","No","Yes","Yes","No")
Mouth.opening <- c("No","No","Yes","Yes","Yes","No","Yes","Yes","No")
Pain.elsewhere <- c("No","Yes","No","No","No","No","No","No","No")
Sleeping <- c("No","No","No","No","No","Yes","No","No","No")
Sore.mouth <- c("No","No","Yes","Yes","No","No","No","No","No")
Swallowing <- c("No","No","No","No","Yes","No","No","No","No")
Cancer.treatment <- c("No","No","Yes","Yes","No","Yes","No","No","No")
Support.for.my.family <- c("No","No","Yes","Yes","No","No","No","No","No")
Fear.of.cancer.coming.back <- c("No","No","Yes","Yes","No","No","Yes","No","No")
Intimacy  <- c("Yes","No","No","No","No","No","No","No","No")
Dentist   <- c("No","Yes","No","No","No","No","No","No","No")
Dietician <- c("No","No","Yes","Yes","No","No","No","No","No")
Date.submitted <- c("2002-07-25 00:00:00",
                 "2002-09-05 00:00:00",
                 "2003-01-09 00:00:00",
                 "2003-01-09 00:00:00",
                 "2003-07-17 00:00:00",
                 "2003-11-06 00:00:00",
                 "2004-12-17 00:00:00",
                 "2005-06-03 00:00:00",
                 "2005-12-17 00:00:00")

theDataFrame <- data.frame( Date.submitted,
                            Appetite,
                            Dental.Health,
                            Dry.mouth,
                            Mouth.opening,
                            Pain.elsewhere,
                            Sleeping,
                            Sore.mouth,
                            Swallowing,
                            Cancer.treatment,
                            Support.for.my.family,
                            Fear.of.cancer.coming.back,
                            Intimacy,
                            Dentist,
                            Dietician)
```

To be clear, this dataframe could contain more (or fewer) observations of more (or fewer) variables than the example above.

My goal is to make a dynamic histogram that looks like the following:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

df <- data.frame(timeline = Sys.Date() - 1:10,
                 q3 = sample(c("Yes", "No"), size = 10, replace = T),
                 q4 = sample(c("Yes", "No"), size = 10, replace = T),
                 q5 = sample(c("Yes", "No"), size = 10, replace = T),
                 q6 = sample(c("Yes", "No"), size = 10, replace = T),
                 q7 = sample(c("Yes", "No"), size = 10, replace = T),
                 q8 = sample(c("Yes", "No"), size = 10, replace = T),

                 stringsAsFactors = F) %>%
    mutate(q3 = ifelse(q3 == "Yes", 1, 0),
           q4 = ifelse(q4 == "Yes", 1, 0),
           q5 = ifelse(q5 == "Yes", 1, 0),
           q6 = ifelse(q6 == "Yes", 1, 0),
           q7 = ifelse(q7 == "Yes", 1, 0),
           q8 = ifelse(q8 == "Yes", 1, 0)

    ) %>%
    gather(key = question, value = value, q3, q4, q5, q6, q7, q8)

g <- ggplot(df, aes(x = timeline, y = value, fill = question)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity")

g
```

I think I will need to use library(lubridate) for the timeline, as the entire dataframe is plain text.  I deal with the '.' in the column names like this:

```
myColNames <- colnames(theDataFrame)

myNames <- myColNames

myNames <- gsub("^X\\.\\.", "", myNames)
myNames <- gsub("\\.", " ", myNames)
names(theDataFrame) <- myNames # items in myChoices get "labels" from myNames
```

But the most challenging aspect is getting this to work dynamically.  The datasets will only contain Date.submitted and (x)number of additional columns that will only be "Yes" or "No"

I hope I've given enough information (this is my first question on Stack Exchange!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can update it using `base R`

```
theDataFrame[-1] <- +(theDataFrame[-1]=="Yes")
```

Or with `lapply` when the dataset is big

```
theDataFrame[-1] <- lapply(theDataFrame[-1], function(x) as.integer(x=="Yes"))
```

Comment: I've gotten as far as this, but i can't seem to get my head around the last bit...  I'll post a new question

Comment: and then this doesn't work...|
...
 stringsAsFactors = F) %>%
    theDataFrame[-1] <- lapply(theDataFrame[-1], function(x) as.integer(x=="Yes")) %>%
    gather(key = question, value = value, as.list(theDataFrame))

is.character(x) is not TRUE   I'm confused

Comment: @JasonJorgenson  Not sure I get your second comment

Comment: sorry.  I was trying to fit it into a comment.   See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42506600/dynamic-r-dataframes-change-yes-no-responses-to-1-0/42506628#42506628

Comment: @JasonJorgenson  I undersatnd why your code didn't work.  You are using `%>%` to connect.  I think the `dplyr way should be `mutate_all` similar to the one in the other answer. i.e. `theDataFrame %>% mutate_each(funs(as.initeger(.=="Yes")), -1) %>% gather(key = question, value = value, -1)`

Comment: @JasonJorgenson  I tested with the data you showed.  `theDataFrame %>% mutate_each(funs(as.integer(.=="Yes")), -1) %>% gather(key = question, value = value, -1) %>% ggplot(., aes(x= Date.submitted, y = value, fill=question)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")` works for me

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `dplyr::mutate_all` and `purrr::map`

Note: I used `stringsAsFactors = F` in `theDataFrame`

```
theDataFrame <- data.frame( Date.submitted,
                            Appetite,
                            Dental.Health,
                            Dry.mouth,
                            Mouth.opening,
                            Pain.elsewhere,
                            Sleeping,
                            Sore.mouth,
                            Swallowing,
                            Cancer.treatment,
                            Support.for.my.family,
                            Fear.of.cancer.coming.back,
                            Intimacy,
                            Dentist,
                            Dietician, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

-Create a function to do the conversion you want, for instance:

```
ConvertYesNo<- function(x){
  if(x=="Yes") y <- as.integer(1)
  else if (x=="No") y <- as.integer(0)
  else y <- x

  return(y)
}
```

-Use it with `mutate_all`, which considers all the columns or pick the columns you want using `mutate_at`. And `map` the function as follows:

```
theDataFramex <- theDataFrame %>% 
  mutate_all(funs(map_chr(.,ConvertYesNo)))

> head(theDataFramex,3 )
       Date.submitted Appetite Dental.Health Dry.mouth Mouth.opening Pain.elsewhere Sleeping
1 2002-07-25 00:00:00        0             0         0             0              0        0
2 2002-09-05 00:00:00        1             1         1             0              1        0
3 2003-01-09 00:00:00        0             0         1             1              0        0
  Sore.mouth Swallowing Cancer.treatment Support.for.my.family Fear.of.cancer.coming.back
1          0          0                0                     0                          0
2          0          0                0                     0                          0
3          1          0                1                     1                          1
  Intimacy Dentist Dietician
1        1       0         0
2        0       1         0
3        0       0         1
```

Comment: Thanks OmaymaS.  This was helpful!