# Dynamic R histogram from dataframe created using LimeSurvey API response

Tags: r, dynamic, dataframe, ggplot2, limesurvey

Step one of my goal was realised (Thanks @akrun), but I can't seem to quite cross the goal line!  Carrying on with my first question that was answered very quickly, I am still unable to create the histogram.

This is a working example of what I want my dynamic output to look like:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
df <- data.frame(timeline = Sys.Date() - 1:10,
                 q3 = sample(c("Yes", "No"), size = 10, replace = T),
                 q4 = sample(c("Yes", "No"), size = 10, replace = T),
                 q5 = sample(c("Yes", "No"), size = 10, replace = T),
                 q6 = sample(c("Yes", "No"), size = 10, replace = T),
                 q7 = sample(c("Yes", "No"), size = 10, replace = T),
                 q8 = sample(c("Yes", "No"), size = 10, replace = T),

                 stringsAsFactors = F) %>%
    mutate(q3 = ifelse(q3 == "Yes", 1, 0),
           q4 = ifelse(q4 == "Yes", 1, 0),
           q5 = ifelse(q5 == "Yes", 1, 0),
           q6 = ifelse(q6 == "Yes", 1, 0),
           q7 = ifelse(q7 == "Yes", 1, 0),
           q8 = ifelse(q8 == "Yes", 1, 0)

    ) %>%
    gather(key = question, value = value, q3, q4, q5, q6, q7, q8)

g <- ggplot(df, aes(x = timeline, y = value, fill = question)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity")

g
```

and this is where I got to after [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42506600/dynamic-r-dataframes-change-yes-no-responses-to-1-0) This is an example of the dataframe that gets created.  I won't know the number of columns, their names, or the number of observations so it has to work dynamically.

```
Appetite <- c("No","Yes","No","No","No","No","No","No","No")
Dental.Health <- c("No","Yes","No","No","No","No","Yes","Yes","No")
Dry.mouth <- c("No","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","No","Yes","Yes","No")
Mouth.opening <- c("No","No","Yes","Yes","Yes","No","Yes","Yes","No")
Pain.elsewhere <- c("No","Yes","No","No","No","No","No","No","No")
Sleeping <- c("No","No","No","No","No","Yes","No","No","No")
Sore.mouth <- c("No","No","Yes","Yes","No","No","No","No","No")
Swallowing <- c("No","No","No","No","Yes","No","No","No","No")
Cancer.treatment <- c("No","No","Yes","Yes","No","Yes","No","No","No")
Support.for.my.family <- c("No","No","Yes","Yes","No","No","No","No","No")
Fear.of.cancer.coming.back <- c("No","No","Yes","Yes","No","No","Yes","No","No")
Intimacy  <- c("Yes","No","No","No","No","No","No","No","No")
Dentist   <- c("No","Yes","No","No","No","No","No","No","No")
Dietician <- c("No","No","Yes","Yes","No","No","No","No","No")
Date.submitted <- c("2002-07-25 00:00:00",
                 "2002-09-05 00:00:00",
                 "2003-01-09 00:00:00",
                 "2003-01-09 00:00:00",
                 "2003-07-17 00:00:00",
                 "2003-11-06 00:00:00",
                 "2004-12-17 00:00:00",
                 "2005-06-03 00:00:00",
                 "2005-12-17 00:00:00")

theDates <- as.Date(Date.submitted, "%Y-%m-%d %T")

theDataFrame <- data.frame( timeline = as.list(theDates),
                            Appetite,
                            Dental.Health,
                            Dry.mouth,
                            Mouth.opening,
                            Pain.elsewhere,
                            Sleeping,
                            Sore.mouth,
                            Swallowing,
                            Cancer.treatment,
                            Support.for.my.family,
                            Fear.of.cancer.coming.back,
                            Intimacy,
                            Dentist,
                            Dietician,
                            stringsAsFactors = F) %>%
    theDataFrame[-1] <- lapply(theDataFrame[-1], function(x) as.integer(x=="Yes")) %>%
    gather(key = question, value = value, as.list(theDataFrame))

go <- ggplot(theDataFrame, aes(x = timeline, y = value, fill = question)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity")

go
```

I am probably misunderstanding how gather works, but I can't seem to get my head around it.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Your working example works for me. What do you want to change?

Comment: I need to get the second one to work.  The dataframe that I created is an example of what gets returned from an API call to LimeSurvey.  Because there will be different numbers of variables and observations, it has to work dynamically (without knowing the number/names of any columns)

Answer (score 0):

[In his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42508621/dynamic-r-histogram-from-dataframe-created-using-limesurvey-api-response#comment72155480_42508621), the OP requested to get the second example to work. This can be accomplished with a few modifications to the OP's code:

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

Appetite <- c("No","Yes","No","No","No","No","No","No","No")
Dental.Health <- c("No","Yes","No","No","No","No","Yes","Yes","No")
Dry.mouth <- c("No","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","No","Yes","Yes","No")
Mouth.opening <- c("No","No","Yes","Yes","Yes","No","Yes","Yes","No")
Pain.elsewhere <- c("No","Yes","No","No","No","No","No","No","No")
Sleeping <- c("No","No","No","No","No","Yes","No","No","No")
Sore.mouth <- c("No","No","Yes","Yes","No","No","No","No","No")
Swallowing <- c("No","No","No","No","Yes","No","No","No","No")
Cancer.treatment <- c("No","No","Yes","Yes","No","Yes","No","No","No")
Support.for.my.family <- c("No","No","Yes","Yes","No","No","No","No","No")
Fear.of.cancer.coming.back <- c("No","No","Yes","Yes","No","No","Yes","No","No")
Intimacy  <- c("Yes","No","No","No","No","No","No","No","No")
Dentist   <- c("No","Yes","No","No","No","No","No","No","No")
Dietician <- c("No","No","Yes","Yes","No","No","No","No","No")
Date.submitted <- 
  c("2002-07-25 00:00:00", "2002-09-05 00:00:00", "2003-01-09 00:00:00",
    "2003-01-09 00:00:00", "2003-07-17 00:00:00", "2003-11-06 00:00:00",
    "2004-12-17 00:00:00", "2005-06-03 00:00:00", "2005-12-17 00:00:00")

theDataFrame <- data.frame(
  timeline = as.Date(Date.submitted),
  Appetite, Dental.Health, Dry.mouth, Mouth.opening, Pain.elsewhere,
  Sleeping, Sore.mouth, Swallowing, Cancer.treatment, Support.for.my.family,
  Fear.of.cancer.coming.back, Intimacy, Dentist, Dietician,
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

theDataFrame[-1] <- lapply(theDataFrame[-1], function(x) as.integer(x=="Yes")) 
theDataFrame <- theDataFrame %>% gather(question, value, -timeline)

go <- ggplot(theDataFrame, aes(x = timeline, y = value, fill = question)) +
  geom_col()
go
```

[image]